# Maximun amount of IP-addresses per load balancer in Google Cloud

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

What is the maximum amount of Ip addresses (SSL enabled domains) per Google Cloud load balancer? I'm trying to find out how much we can scale our application on one load balancer setup. Or will the load balancer slow down because of a large number of different domains (with SSL certificates) attached to it?

I noticed that there is a limitation of 15 SSL certificates / Ip-address and a limit of 100 HTTPS proxies on one project. I think that 100 limitation can be grown by asking from google, but does it make sense?

Our current project has now almost 100 domains (with SSL certs) attached to one load balancer and we have plans to host thousands of hosts within the same application. Should we consider another kind of approach or set up multiple load balancers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Google Managed Certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#ssl_certificates) you can configure up to 100 non-wildcard domains per SSL Certificate, also you can use up to [15 Google Managed Certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#target_pools_and_target_proxies) per target HTTPS or target SSL proxy, this means that you can use [multiple SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#multiplessl) when you are serving from multiple domains using the same Load Balancer IP address and port, this allows you to configure up to 1500 domains (100 per SSL Certificate) per target HTTPS or target SSL proxy, please be advised that those quotas are hard limit and could not be increased

Best regards

Comment: Do you know if the quota of Target HTTPS proxies can be asked for any higher? It seems like ours is now 30.  Or any higher than that 100? 

And how is the load balancing cluster designed to act if there is the maximum amount of HTTPS proxies and SSL certs on? Is still fast and reliable?

Comment: Yes you can increase the current Target HTTPS proxies quota, typically the limit is 30 Target HTTPS proxies per project, if you want to increase this limit, it is recommended to select the Target HTTPS proxies quota, click on “Edit quota” and set the new limit, Regarding your last question, I share with you a document that explains how https lb works[link] https://cloud.google.com/architecture/about-capacity-optimization-with-global-lb#how_https_load_balancing_works, I trust if you are experiencing issues in your configuration after hitting the limits it is recommended to open a support case